# How can I get every nth row using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get every nth row from the table. I can do something like this in sql:

```
select * from [table] where [table].row_number % n=0;
```

But how can I do this in hibernate using hql?

Comment: Afraid, you can't. You ca do it just manually, after all rows have been selected.

Comment: An addition to @KenBekov's comment. You could retrieve all ID's with one select statement, then choose every n-th and with second select statement load them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of `setFirstResult(n)` and `setMaxResults(1)` of Query class.

setting n to setFirstResult and 1 to setMaxResults can give the desired result.

check link [setFirstResult](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult(int))  and [setMaxResults](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int))